# Order of Classes within an Assembly

Tags: c#, class, compiler-construction, .net-assembly

What determines the order of classes within an Assembly?

And.. is there a way to change it?

---

Additional info: you can check the ordering either through reflection yourself, or you can use a tool like ILDASM, disable the alphabetical sorting, and then you will also get the order.

Order seems to be in a strange way determined by the compiler.

I already tried some things.. like renaming the classes (order stays the same), also editing the .csproj file to change the order of the .cs files.

My main focus is VS2008, C#, .net 3.5.

---

Update: I do have a scenario where the order matters (external program going through my assembly through reflection) - and I need special order there.
Apart from this - you are totally right - order really should not matter.

Comment: Is there something you're trying to solve or work around or is this just for curiosity's sake. i.e. what does it matter?

Comment: Coincidentally, I believe @EricLippert just wrote [a blog post that's related to this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/31/past-performance-is-no-guarantee-of-future-results.aspx).

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: The order should not matter at all, as the order is not guaranteed. If the order matters, then your third-party code is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to stick my neck out here and say this is an **implementation detail** and may well be decided by any particular compiler.

Since this is an implementation detail you shouldn't or needn't be concerned.  Of course if this really is important (can't see why) you can always write your own IL.

I leave you with the following quote from [Eric's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/31/past-performance-is-no-guarantee-of-future-results.aspx):

> Is compiling the same C# program twice guaranteed to produce the same
>   binary output?
>
> No.

Comment: Thx, Eric's blog entry is pretty interesting.

It does not explain much, though.

Also, if you look at the comment, I would say about a quarter have had the same problem at least once. :)

Some actually had to go to specific compilers/languages for that requirement (no, not me!). Oh, and.. I really don't see the point of a compile being nondeterministic. I mean.. there might be optimization algorithms involved with a random part, but.. hmm.. I would rather doubt that this is the case.

He also only argues that ouput is different mainly because of generated GUIDs and the like.

Comment: Compilers can be non-deterministic. For e.g. a compiler can use multiple threads to compile types (or classes) in an assembly after a cycle of type dependency resolving logic. As and when a thread completes compiling a type, the compiler can add an entry for that type in the metadata. Since thread scheduling is non-deterministic, order of metadata entries and hence order of classes in an assembly become non-deterministic. I am not saying this is how things actually work but it is easy to see that compiler can quite easily be non-deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

> What determines the order of classes within an Assembly?

The compiler.

> And.. is there a way to change it?

Write your own IL directly.

---

That being said, the order of the types within the assembly really doesn't matter.  You can use the types with no regard to their order.