# Ordering of types fetched from Assembly.GetTypes()

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a requirement in which i need to get the types as below

```
public class Class1
{
}

public class Class2 : Class1
{
}

public class Class3 : Class1
{
}
```

I can call the `Assembly.GetTypes()` on the target assembly and add all the classes that derive from `Class1`. I am ordering the types so that next time, that order will be used.
That order is essential for internal serialization and deserialization as the internal engine depends on the index of the type rather than the type name. I can not alter the serialization engine.

If in future a new class `Class4` is derived from `Class1`, then it should come in the order after `Class3`.

I am not able to think of a solution that is feasible.

Do, i need to maintain a xml file in which the order of the types are preserved and if i encounter a new type, should that be added at the end of xml?

Please help

Comment: You cannot rely on any order of the types returned by the GetTypes method. If you have some custom rules for ordering then you should apply those rules on the results returned by the method.

Comment: (De)serialization of types based on an arbitrary index instead of the type name itself requires a mapping between the indices and the respective types. That's what you basically do with your XML, and I guess this approach is the best option in this situation. Such a XML/text file is easily maintainable and verifiable. (There might be other approaches such as creating custom type attributes or somehow putting the serialization index number in the type name, but those approaches are cumbersome and error-prone.)

Comment: Ordering of classes in an assembly is arbitrary, you cannot rely on anything http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213732/order-of-classes-within-an-assembly . You will need an additional mechanism, like the .xml you talked about or as outlined in the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

You can create any custom rule for ordering: for example. The pattern is `{ClassName}{Index}`

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {

        Type baseClass = typeof(Class1);
        var result = (from type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                      where type.IsSubclassOf(baseClass)
                      let index = Regex.Match(type.Name, @"\d+$")
                      where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(index.Value) == false
                      select new ResultItem { Index = int.Parse(index.Value), Type = type })
                      .OrderBy(x=>x.Index)
                      .ToList();
        result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    public class Class1
    {
    }

    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
    }

    public class Class3 : Class1
    {
    }

    private sealed class ResultItem
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public Type Type { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Index: {0}, Type: {1}", Index, Type.Name);
        }
    }
```

Result output:

```
Index: 2, Type: Class2
Index: 3, Type: Class3
```

So, you can add any new classes.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i have provided the classes for illustrative purpose only, in actual the class names can be anything. In that case, i need to have the type name as the key and a fixed index for that type.

Comment: If class name can be anything, so you can mark them by your attribute or create Key Value section in the config file where Key is a type and Value is an oder.